# Disabling the edittext by default by unchecking the checkbox error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox

I have one question. I want my edittext to be initially disabled. It will be only enabled when I check the checkbox. What is happening is, when i launch the app, the checkbox has no check but i can edit the edittext. To disable the edittext, i have to check then uncheck again the text box. Can you help me?

here is my code:

```
check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
});
```

When using 2 checkboxes for 2 different edittext. My app crashes when pressing the second checkbox. Heres the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.order);  
txtbox1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText5);  
txtbox2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkcheck);
check2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkcheckcheck);
button1.setOnClickListener(new clicker());



check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(true);
        txtbox1.setFocusable(true);
    } else {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(false);
        txtbox1.setFocusable(false);
    }
}
```

});

```
check2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        txtbox2.setEnabled(true);
        txtbox2.setFocusable(true);
    } else {
        txtbox2.setEnabled(false);
        txtbox2.setFocusable(false);
    }
}
```

});

}

Logcat:
[image: Logcat]

Comment: disable the edittext in your xml and enable it only when user checks the checkbox.

Comment: Do you have `android:enabled="false"` in your xml?

Comment: Yes. I forgot that one. Thanks!

Comment: See my updated post. Having a new problem. @Raghunandan

Comment: I solved it. I entered wrong id. Hehe:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do u invoke the `txtbox1.setEnabled(false);` in the `onCreate()` ?
the onCheckChanged will not invoked at the very begining.

Comment: semms the 54 in in Order.java?

Comment: I solved it. I entered wrong id. Next time I'll check. Double check! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
txtbox1.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file use
`android:enabled = "false"` for edittext to disable it initially.

or Programatically write
`txtbox1.setEnabled(false);` in your `onCreate()`.

Then use :

```
check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        txtbox1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When i try two checkboxes disabling different editext. the first checkbox is working but when i click the second one, my app crashes. I'll update my post and post my code.

Comment: you are getting null pointer exception, could u plz post the xml file?

Comment: If there are about 10 edittext boxes should we implement the above method 10 times?